# Knockoutjs - Table Row Click Binding, Want to Exclude Columns from Click Event

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout to bind a click to a row in a table like this:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.selectItem">
```

It works great.  The problem is when I try to exclude certain columns from taking the click action. I am have edit and delete buttons in my row and I don't want them firing the selectItem click event.  Am I going to just have to bind all the td's I want to behave this way to the click event or is there an easier way to do it?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/blankasaurus/WYKEM/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update: you avoid a custom binding by adding `clickBubble: false` as an additional binding with the `click` binding as suggested by Kevin Obee and demonstrated in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinobee/Q25ja/2/

Original: You can use a custom binding that wraps the `click` binding and prevents additional events from happening.  It might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickAndStop = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var handler = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            newValueAccessor = function() {
                return function(data, event) {
                    handler.call(viewModel, data, event);
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
                };
            };

        ko.bindingHandlers.click.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);    
    }
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xj7Hs/